# Dr Java Help inputted equation not working

Tags: java

//In the following lines of code the user is asked to enter a length to determine the volume of a regular icosahedron, however, when entered the programm always outputs 0.0 as the answer for the volume???

```
import java.io.*; //allows I/o statements

class VolumeIcosahedron //creating the 'volumeIcosahedron' class
{
  //allows strings with exceptions to IO = input/output
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader (System.in)); //system input/ output

    String stringNum; // the number string
    double V; // integer with decimals volume
    int L; // integer required length

    //System output
    System.out.println("Hello, what is the required length");
    stringNum  = myInput.readLine();

    L = Integer.parseInt(stringNum);
    V =  5/12 *(3 + Math.sqrt(5))*(L*L*L);                      

    System.out.println("The volume of the regular Icosahedron is " + V);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `5/12` in integer equals `0` so it always results in `0`.

Try with `5.0` to force the division without involving integer division.

```
V = 5.0/12 *(3.0 + Math.sqrt(5))*(L*L*L);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the offending line:

```
V          =  5/12 *(3 + Math.sqrt(5))*(L*L*L);
```

5/12 returns an `int` (whole number), which is always truncated down to 0, hence 0 * anything will return 0.

Change it to this, using the letter d to signify that these numbers are of type double:

```
V          =  5d/12d *(3 + Math.sqrt(5))*(L*L*L);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using integer inside the calculation.
With integer, you should see the division as an euclidean operation, ie a = bq + r.
So in your program, 5/12 will always return 0 (5 = 0 * 12 + 5).

If you change the line to be like this (replacing every integer by double):

```
V = 5.D/12.D *(3.D + Math.sqrt(5.D))*(L*L*L);
```

Then the result will be different.